Formalization of "categories up to equivalence"
For topological spaces, it is generally easy to guess if a property is "topological" (that is, a property that is preserved by homeomorphisms). Because, if we are given an abstract topological space $(X, \tau),$ then any property that you are able to express that does not depend on the particular elements of $X, \tau$ is topological.
Similarly, a property that can be defined on an abstract ring and that does not depend on its particular elements will always be preserved by group isomorphisms. This works for a great variety of algebraic structures.
However, in the typical presentation of category theory, it is very easy to define properties of a category that are not preserved under categorical equivalence. For example, the cardinality of the set of objects (or objects in a given isomorphism class), is not "categorical".
Question. Is there a way to develop category theory in such a way that every expressible property is categorical?
Informally, I am looking for an approach to category theory that does not distinguish between a category and its skeleton, by the very definition of "category".
On the one hand, the underlying theory for objects should be less expressive than set theory, so that we cannot express the notion of size. On the other hand, for morphisms we want to have sets (or something similar) in order to recover groups of automorphisms. Is something like this possible?

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but with univalent categories, you don't distinguish a category and its skeleton, because the univalence axiom says that isomorphism implies equality.

@Sambo Yes, I think univalent categories might be what I'm after. Do you know of an easy reference where category theory is developed in this fashion?

Not really, sorry - I only dipped my toes into that field. The only reference I'm really aware of is the HoTT book.

I think it is deeply misleading to say that isomorphism implies equality without first clarifying that equality means something vastly richer in HoTT.

Indeed in HoTT the identity types between univalent categories are equivalent to equivalences of categories, so anything you can prove about a univalent category will still hold for an equivalent univalent category.

My idea would be: roughly, any statement which doesn't involve testing "equality of objects" (even behind the scenes) should be equivalence-invariant.  The cardinality of the object set does involve testing equality of objects behind the scenes, because it's equivalent to testing when two object sets have a bijection between them, and both the injective part and the surjective part of the bijection definition would require statements about equality of objects in those sets.

(On the other hand, comparing equality of morphisms, when you know that the domain and codomain are exactly the same respective expressions, is fine.  So for example: equality of functors - "bad"; isomorphism of functors, which only involves comparing morphisms behind the scenes - "OK".)

See also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence
